# Weird result with passing argument(s) in a user-defined step in Gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I've created a user-defined step called `otherV` that starts from an edge (`e`) and takes a single Vertex argument (either `e.inV` or `e.outV`), and outputs the *other* vertex on that edge.

```
Gremlin.defineStep('otherV', [Edge, Pipe], {Vertex v -> _().bothV.filter{!v.equals(it)}})
```

I have `g=TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();`

The `otherV` step gives correct results when I pass the argument vertex like this:

```
g.v(1).bothE('knows').otherV(g.v(1)).path{it.name}{it.label}
==>[marko, knows, vadas]
==>[marko, knows, josh]
```

But, when I first assign the argument vertex to a variable (say, `x`) in a `sideEffect` step, and then pass `x` as argument to my step, it fails with the ERROR `No such property: x for class: groovysh_evaluate`.

```
g.v(1).sideEffect{marko=it}.bothE('knows').otherV(marko).path{it.name}{it.label}
No such property: marko for class: groovysh_evaluate
```

What's it that I'm doing wrong?

---

Here is a simple illustration of how the `otherV` custom-step is supposed to work:

```
// g is the TinkerGraph
marko = g.v(1); vadas = g.v(2); 
edge = g.e(7); // e[7][1-knows->2]

gremlin> edge.otherV(marko).map
==>{name=vadas, age=27}

gremlin> edge.otherV(vadas).map
==>{name=marko, age=29}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is has to do with scoping of variables within closures.  I've restructured your defineStep to hopefully capture what you are after:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()                                                                                     
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> Gremlin.defineStep('otherV', [Vertex, Pipe], {l -> _().sideEffect{x=it}.bothE(l).bothV.filter{!x.equals(it)}})                          
==>null
gremlin> g.v(1).otherV("knows").path{it.name}{it.label}
==>[marko, knows, vadas]
==>[marko, knows, josh]
```

This seems like a more succinct way to define your custom step as well.

---

Here's another approach to the otherV step that takes an arbitrary edge and outputs the other vertex:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()                                  
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> Gremlin.defineStep('otherV', [Edge, Pipe], {v -> l=[v];_().bothV.except(l).gather.transform{it.size()>1?null:it[0]}})
==>null
gremlin> g.e(11).otherV(g.v(3))
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.e(11).otherV(g.v(4))
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.e(11).otherV(g.v(5))
==>null
```

Someone will probably come along with a better way to do this, but basically I realized that it's not enough to simply evaluate if the vertex from bothV in the defineStep is the opposite of the one passed in because it's possible that it matches neither the head nor the tail.  Basically, I used except() to get the opposing vertex to the one passed in, then gathered whatever didn't match into a list, then checked the list to see if the size is greater than one.  If it is, then that means that the vertex passed in was neither in the head or tail of the edge (and I return null), otherwise the single vertex in the list is the opposing one.

Comment: Thanks, stephen. Yes, it doesn't fail, but, please notice that there are two extra paths, both `[marko, knows, marko]`, in the result. However, when passing `otherV(g.v(1))` only two correct paths are returned (as shown in the first case in my question.)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I suppose I was excited to see something other than an error and figured I had things right.  I've re-worked my answer a lot.

Comment: Thanks, your modification to the custom step works fine with the particular example in my question. However, my idea for the `otherV` step was to start from any edge and, given one of its vertices, to return the other vertex, regardless of the edge-label. I've added a simple illustration at the end of my question.

Comment: I revised my answer again to answer the second part of your question.